# Best way to encrypt some selected rows

Tags: sql-server

I know how to create a new column based on an old one , encrypt it after creating a master key/certificate and etc.

I would like to know what would be the best approach to encrypt ceartin columns without the need to create a new one.

I mean, is there a way to encrypt a column, and during a select, we see encrypt data or something like `J&Y@HS@H&HS` and only some users can see it?

I'm not talking about TDE in the entire database or backup encryption.

Thanks.

Comment: This could help --> https://www.sqlshack.com/an-overview-of-the-column-level-sql-server-encryption/

Comment: Thanks @Learning_DBAdmin I was looking that website right now. and it does exactly what I said, it creates a new column based in an old one.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for [data masking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/dynamic-data-masking?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 1):

[Dynamic Data Masking (DDM)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/dynamic-data-masking?view=sql-server-ver15#security-note-bypassing-masking-using-inference-or-brute-force-techniques) can fulfil the requirement as long as the Least Privilege Principle followed, since by default members of `sysadmin` server role and members of `db_owner` database role can always see UNMASKED (Including Encrypted columns).

If the requirement as such that even `sysadmin` role members must only see the encrypted data then the better fit will be [Always Encrypted feature...](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/always-encrypted-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15)

Or, if the goal is just to protect some sensitive data within database when it restored into DEV/UAT environments, better look for reliable third-party solution, or you can also develop you're own stored procedure/script that can be executed (manually) in DEV DB every time a restoration happened.